# removing print statements in python using eclipse or pycharm

Tags: python, eclipse, pycharm

I have looked on stackoverflow but didn't find the answer i was looking for.
 I have a bunch of python files and was using "print" liberally to debug. Now I want to get rid of every print statement since none of my python files is expected to print anything to stdout (It is a backend code for a web app). How do I get rid of my 'print's? I could have simply searched 'print' and replace it with "#print" but some of the print statements are multi-line.

Is there a way to do it using Elipse (preferrably) or PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for every occurrence of `print` and replace with:

```
if __debug__: print
```

When run using Python's `-o` (optimize) command line flag, which you can easily do in your production environment, these statements will then be stripped entirely, as if they were never there. They remain in place to help you with debugging when running Python without `-o`.